# What happens when adding swimming pool salt to a freshwater pool?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why does adding swimming pool salt to a freshwater swimming pool cause a white sediment to build up and stick to the floor of the pool?

Comment: Because the salt did not dissolve?

Comment: First of, what do you understand by "swimming pool salt"? There are millions of different "salts".

Comment: Salt used in swimming pools is exactly like table salt.  The only difference is, the salt is ground more finely to motivate faster, more complete dissolution.  Clearly some salt did not dissolve fast enough.  Pools that use chlorinators (a device built into the pump's pipeline) generally require salt to produce chlorine.